# Excel macro to find words from Google Translate

Tags: vba, excel, google-translate, vocabulary

I have an Excel sheet with almost 30.000 words in column A and I want to create a macro to search each word in Google Translate, get their meaning (or translation), put the meaing in column B (or if there is more than more meaning in column C, column D, etc.)
Since I have almost 30.000 words, it is a very time consuming thing to search for each word by myself. It would be great if I can do this with a macro.
Any suggestions? (Google Translate is not a "must" for me. If there is another web-site or some other way to do this, I am open to suggestions)

Note: I came across with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981547/finding-the-english-definition-of-a-word-in-vba) topic, but it did not work out the way I hoped.

Comment: Google search starts CAPTHA verifications around 100 searches it deems robotic. Have you checked to make sure that Google Translate doesn't do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Google Translate API is not the free service it's  tricker to perform this operation. However, I found a workaround on this page [Translate text using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098260/translate-text-using-vba) and I made some adjustments so it could work for your purposes. Assuming that the original words are entered into the "A" column in the spreadsheet and translations should appear in the colums on the right here is the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String

Dim detailed_translation_results, basic_translation_results
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        detailed_translation_results = detailed_translation(cell.Value)

        'Check whether detailed_translation_results is an array value. If yes, each detailed translation is entered into separate column, if not, basic translation is entered into the next column on the right
        On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, UBound(detailed_translation_results) + 1)).Value = detailed_translation_results

            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = detailed_translation_results
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next cell

End Sub

Function detailed_translation(str)
' Tools Refrence Select Microsoft internet Control

Dim IE As Object, i As Long, j As Long
Dim inputstring As String, outputstring As String, text_to_convert As String, result_data As String, CLEAN_DATA
Dim FirstTablePosition As Long, FinalTablePosition

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

'   Choose input language - Default "auto"

inputstring = "auto"

'   Choose input language - Default "en"

outputstring = "en"

text_to_convert = str

'open website

IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & inputstring & "/" & outputstring & "/" & text_to_convert

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'Firstly, this function tries to extract detailed translation.

Dim TempTranslation() As String, FinalTranslation() As String

FirstTablePosition = InStr(IE.Document.getElementById("gt-lc").innerHTML, "<tbody>")
LastTablePosition = InStr(IE.Document.getElementById("gt-lc").innerHTML, "</tbody>")

On Error Resume Next
TempTranslation() = Split(Mid(IE.Document.getElementById("gt-lc").innerHTML, FirstTablePosition, LastTablePosition - FirstTablePosition), "class=""gt-baf-cell gt-baf-word-clickable"">")

ReDim FinalTranslation(0 To UBound(TempTranslation) - 1)

For j = LBound(TempTranslation) + 1 To UBound(TempTranslation)
    FinalTranslation(j - 1) = Left(TempTranslation(j), InStr(TempTranslation(j), "<") - 1)
Next j
On Error GoTo 0

Dim CheckIfDetailed

'Check whether there is detailed translation available. If not - this function returns a single translation
On Error Resume Next
    CheckIfDetailed = FinalTranslation(LBound(FinalTranslation))

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        CLEAN_DATA = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(IE.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML, "</SPAN>", ""), "<")

        For j = LBound(CLEAN_DATA) To UBound(CLEAN_DATA)

            result_data = result_data & Right(CLEAN_DATA(j), Len(CLEAN_DATA(j)) - InStr(CLEAN_DATA(j), ">"))
        Next

        detailed_translation = result_data
        Exit Function

    End If
On Error GoTo 0

IE.Quit

detailed_translation = FinalTranslation()


End Function
```

Please note that the code is extremly slow (due to anti-robot restrictions) and I cannot guarantee that Google will not block the script. However, it should work.

The only thing you should do is to choose languages in the places marked by the appropriate comment.

Alternatively, if you seek something faster, you can manipulate Application.Wait method (for example setting the value to 0:00:2 instead of 0:00:5) or google for Microsoft Translate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But did you try this? I tried this with two words in A column. I wrote "Home" to A1 and "Test" to A2 and ran the code that you provided. I saw that it tried to do something but nothing happened. I will try to look into your suggestion and the code that was in the link that you provided.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Please find a link to YT where I show how this macro works. (http://youtu.be/E6zvz3o-SW4)

Comment: Wow, you really did try that :)
Ok so I must be having another problem. Since I can run other macros, my macros are enabled. But when I run the macro just as you did on your video (copy from here and paste in my vba editor and run it), it just waits some time and nothing happens. I think I have to do some other thing for this macro to work.
Anyway, A for the effort man. Thank you very much :)